# Multiple Web-Based Clients Interacting within a Game

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a web-based game with 6 players on a team. Node.js runs the server-side for everyone (express, mongodb), with html/javascript on the front end.

I'm not sure how to let the players "interact" by receiving game updates in real time on their client from the server. For example, Player 1 clicks a button, the action is sent to the server, and all other players receive this information from the server. Or Player 1 clicks on an item and all other players then have the item disappear from their screens. Or Player 3 votes to go in east, and all other players see that vote. I'm not sure how to have the javascript wait for and react to actions from the server.

I realize this is a basic conceptual question but my training didn't touch on this. I will need to do this often, and I can't even get past the point where Player 1 clicks to start the game and the other players then are taken to the next location.

Any help is greatly appreciated, even just pointing me to a resource to learn. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to use web sockets. Read about web sockets and then look up socket.io; it is a library that will make it easy to use web sockets.